# Oracle SOA Suite 12c - Long Response time for the first call

Tags: oracle, soa, oracle12c

We have `REST` Web-Services created in `Oracle SOA suite 12c`.

After every server restart the first call to the Service is taking more time (like `18000ms`) than usual (`2000`-`3000ms`).

After a couple of service requests things are coming back to normality.

Is there any specific reason for this and is there a way to alleviate this problem?

Comment: This is happening due to lazy loading setting in the SOA EM console. We can override that property in the composite level as well

Answer (score 2):

This is happening due to lazy loading setting in the SOA EM console. We can override that property in the composite level as well